# obtaining a vector of non removed index rows

Tags: r

I have two data frames which have the same elements initially but after  eliminating some rows in one of them are not the same length.

```
x <-c(4,2,3,6,7,3,1,8,5,2,4,1,2,6,3)
y <-c(1,4,2,3,6,7,3,1,8,5,2,3,1,4,3)
z <-c(4,2,3,1,8,5,2,4,1)
k <-c(1,4,2,3,1,8,5,2,3)

df1 <- data.frame(x,y)
df2 <- data.frame(z,k)
```

I would like to find a way in the second data frame (df2) to create a row or have the index reference with the index row number of the first data frame (df1) so it results in a new data frame as follows (a would be the index reference from df1).

```
  df3
   a z k
1  1 4 1
2  2 2 4
3  3 3 2
4  7 1 3
5  8 8 1
6  9 5 8
7  10 2 5
8  11 4 2
9  12 1 3
```

I could create a column manually of all rows that are eliminated or use

```
library(sqldf)
a1NotIna2 <- (sqldf('SELECT * FROM df1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM df2'))
a1NotIna2 

  x y
1 2 1
2 3 3
3 3 7
4 6 3
5 6 4
6 7 6
```

I have tried using -which- without sucess on this last expression to find out the rows of df1 that were eliminated to be used this in removing from a sequencing vector of length equal to df1 those common elements as to obtain a vector with the index similar to df3

Any help is welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic solution if your data.frames have two columns, using `pmatch`:

```
transform(df2, a=pmatch(do.call(paste0, df2), do.call(paste0, df1)))
#  z k  a
#1 4 1  1
#2 2 4  2
#3 3 2  3
#4 1 3  7
#5 8 1  8
#6 5 8  9
#7 2 5 10
#8 4 2 11
#9 1 3 12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first matching row of `df1` for each row in `df2` with:

```
match(paste(df2$z, df2$k), paste(df1$x, df1$y))
# [1]  1  2  3  7  8  9 10 11  7
```

Unfortunately this won't maintain ordering when you have duplicated rows, so for instance we got index 7 for the last row of `df2` instead of 12.